# How to impersonate a user for a short period to access a page/file?

Tags: asp.net

I'm using FormsAuthentication to allow users to login. However I have a Excel file that gets generated in memory by one of my pages, for example when they go to:

http://www.mywebsite.com/report?date=050809

This generates an Excel report for that date given, in a memory stream and passes it back to the user to download as long as they are logged in. But what I need to do is allow them to access that URL and the Excel report from that link, without having to login manually, is there a quick and dirty way to login them in (impersonate?) for a very short period to get the file and then expire their cookie after a few seconds?

(I'm doing this through asp.net mvc by the way, but it should make no difference I assume in webforms either)

Comment: If someone can access the file without logging in, then why not just remove the protection altogether? I don't really follow...

Comment: Hi Dan, all the other pages are protected except for this one, is there a way just to remove protection for this one from root level? The other option for me is not to remove protection and authenticate them for the request?

Comment: Yeah - as David said you can use location element http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx  - not sure how this works with mvc routing, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to turn off forms authentication for that one page by using the "location" element in your web.config.

Comment: Hi David, would I just set location path to this page? Then set  <allow users="*" />    ??